# How can I append a foreignObject to svg image

Tags: javascript, svg

I have svg image embeded in html like this:

```
<object width="1615" height="534" data="image.svg"></object>
```

SVGDocument is available by:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].getSVGDocument()
```

And I would like to append a foreignObject with custom html to this. Is this possible and how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I suppose.

```
var doc = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].getSVGDocument();
var fo = doc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "foreignObject");
fo.setAttribute("width", "100%");
fo.setAttribute("height", "100%");
var body = doc.createElement("body");
fo.appendChild(body);
// etc to append whatever html content you want...
doc.documentElement.appendChild(fo);
```

Comment: Ok but the main problem is how to fill this foreignObject with some html

Comment: Same way as you add any content to any element. I.e createElement and appendChild

Comment: Ok I already figured it out. Have you tried to append some script tag, looks like it ommits all scripts

Comment: scripts should work but you'd need to ask a new question if you're stuck on that as this question isn't about scripts.